# Paginating a long Markdown document?

Tags: documentation, markdown

I am writing a [handbook for hotplate](http://www.hotplatejs.com/guide.html). It's going to be a lot bigger than I expected. So, I wanted to "break up" the document into several sub-documents.

I am thinking about slicing the documents according to its #titles. So:

```
# Main title

Under main title

## Installation
Under installation

## Initial use
Under initial use
```

Would generate three files:

- maintitle.html -- with a point list pointing to installation.html and initialuse.html ("next")
- installation.html -- with a link to maintitle.html ("prev") and one to initialuse.html ("next)
- initialuse.html -- with links to installation.html ("prev")

It basically breaks up a Markdown file into sections.

Does something like this already exist?

Comment: Pure Markdown does not provide a mechanism for doing this, probably since it was not designed for writing long documents. Something which was designed with this in mind is [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html), which shares some design goals with Markdown (e.g. intended to be easily human-readable in raw form) and was designed to be a general purpose document processing system. The syntax is not very different to Markdown, but it is significantly more powerful. I would really recommend using this (or a similar tool) instead of Markdown for any serious, lengthy writing.

Comment: Also, reStructuredText provides a mechanism for [including documents within other documents](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#including-an-external-document-fragment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"no" (3 years later) I guess this will help people in the future with the same question!